# Сломался сайт Laravel, как запустить (file_put_contents(): Only...)?

Tags: laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что с сайтом, места мало?
сделал команду df -h, вот что показало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что такое етот /dev/sda1
не могу его скачать даже

Comment: /dev/sda1 - это раздел жесткого диска, примерно как диск С или D в виндус. Скорее всего - это раздел в котором лежат все пользовательские файлы. Сайт вроде не ломался, судя по ошибке

Comment: Перейди в свою рабочую директорию и выполни ls -lh - увидишь какие файлы у тебя занимают больше всего места.